# Which HTTP header fields must be re-sent when reusing connection?

Tags: http, web, header, request, protocols

An HTTP connection may be reused for several following requests to the same webserver. And each request contains some header fields. When the connection is reused and several requests are sent, can the header fields of the requests made before be ignored so that the client must send all header fields again (even if they haven't changed)?

What does the specification say about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each message must be self-contained; so you can't leave out header fields sent previously.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the specification section that says that, please?

Comment: [RFC 7230 section 1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-1) defines HTTP as a [*stateless* protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol).